# How do I negate a mathematical statement?

Tags: logic

I just knew that negation uses "not." "Atleast" negates to "less than." "Atmost" negates to "more than." "All" negates to "some." "Some" negates to "none."

How about this, "There are 12 months in a year."
What is the negation of this statement?

Comment: "There are *not* $12$ months in a year."

Comment: The "trichotomy" property. For real numbers $a,b$, either $a<b$, $a>b$ or $a=b$. If one of them is false, one of the other two must be true. If "there are 12" is false then one of "there are less than 12", or "there greater than 12" months in a year must be true.

Comment: The negation of "all" is "not all", which is different than "some". For example it is false that all people have 40 heads, but it is also false that some people have 40 heads.

Comment: The negation of “All *do* (something)“ is “Some *do not* (that thing)“  It is false that all people have 40 heads, because I do not have 40 heads.

Comment: As a general rule, you want to think about the _meaning_ of the negation to choose how to say it. Don't rely on mechanical  rules for substituting words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply say: "There are not 12 months in a year"

Or, you could say: "There are either less than 12, or more than 12, months in a year"